# How to get parent onclick be function again after disable by child onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have problem to enable again onclick function in parent when I disable it using child onclick.My expected result it's working again when click on parent function,but it's not working.So,below is my code.

```
function showUserInfo(ini){
   $(ini).on("click", showUserInfo);
   $(ini).find('.status').html('<i onClick="recentOpen(this)" class="fa fa-eye eyeMark"></i>');
 }

function recentOpen(ini){
   $(ini).closest('.userIntro').prop("onclick", null);
   $(ini).remove();    
}
```

HTML CODE like:

```
<div onClick="showUserInfo(this)" class="userIntro"> 
  <div>Intro</div>
  <div class="status"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When / where do you want to re-enable the parent click?

Comment: when click on parent function again.

Comment: That makes no sense. The click on the child disables the event for the parent, so how can a click on the parent re-enable itself?

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix your event handler ways. If I understand correctly, there's no need to remove any event handler functions, you just need to prevent event bubbling:

```
// Attach event handler to userIntro
$('.userIntro').on('click', function(){

    // Append FA Icon
    $(this).find('.status').html('<i class="fa fa-eye eyeMark">FA</i>');

// Add another handler, this time test whether the target
// is the <i> (using on()) we already appended
}).on('click', '.status > .fa', function(e){

    // Prevent the event from bubbling so the previous
    // function isn't invoked
    e.stopPropagation();

    //Remove the icon.
   $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Or, attach the event handler to the icon before appending it:

```
$('.userIntro').on('click', function(){
    var $fa = $('<i class="fa fa-eye eyeMark">FA</i>').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $(this).find('.status').append($fa);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/12jqw46k/)

Comment: Thanks,but I have to use onclick function because I want to get more parameter in actual code.But,has a way to do as my code above.?

Comment: @adam You can use `data-*` attributes to give HTML elements extra data, then get that data using jQuery.